# Creating a "Submitted by user on mm/dd/yy 12:00PM" field

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I'm working on an InfoPath 2013 form and I was wondering how can I make a time stamp once the authorized user clicks the submit button. For example, security admin clicks submit then a field next to the button displays "Submitted by Security Admin on mm/dd/yy 12:00PM"

Many thanks!

Comment: If you get it working than can you please accept the answer so other users will get the correct information from it in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want success message after submitting a form than you can use one more view after form's submit event & you can enter whatever the message you need.

Please check below URL for the reference.

[Steps to Create a “Successfully Submitted” Message](http://rippleeffect.com/2011/05/infopathsubmitmessage/)

Comment: Does the message stays though? The form is a custom list item divided by three departments and I need them to see when their department submitted their changes.

Comment: If your form do have multiple submit buttons than you should create the label & enable it on the action of the button by validating it. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That's correct, I need a label next to the submit buttons. What rule could I use?

Comment: You might be using submit buttons rather than buttons that run rules which submit.  The difference is that a submit button will always submit using the main submit data connection whereas with rules you can specify which connection to use.  In the button properties, make sure you select Rules and Custom Code.  Then create a rule on the button so that it submits using the proper submit connection based on the department.  Hopefully that should do the trick for you.

Comment: Please check here...http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/17908.aspx

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Not yet, I don't get the submit and rule option button in infopath 2013. The buttons I made are action buttons though, I wonder if I can put a field then a rule "when button click set current date and time"on that field. Is this possible?

Comment: On the button right click & open properties. check the submit functionality in the Tools > Submit Options. & there will be a line called create custom rule.

Comment: Ok than you can create a rule to display the message.

Comment: Have you got it working? do you need any other help?

Comment: Did you created the label to show the message? or you used default functionality(popup)? BTW but i want to know.

Comment: I added the label